# How to find dynamicly added string?

Tags: java, selenium

How can I check if new appending element's text is equal to string?
I want to find a word in a chat, but looks like I am pointing to the same element.

```
while (true){
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='msg-body']"), "Hello"));
            System.out.println("Found Hello");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Nothing found");
        }
            Thread.sleep(100);
    }
```

The part of chat HTML

```
<li class="msg-chat-message">
            <span class="user role-user">
                <img class="user-logo" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d6/d6e4e034324f1e2abe161a8239f243a2f48e08e9.jpg">
                    <div class="user-level-container">
                        <div class="user-level level-item level-70">75</div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="drop-down-container _3_options">
                        <ul class="user-dropdown-invisible">
                            <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Stats</li>
                            <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Tip</li>
                            <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Ignore</li>
                            <!-- react-text: 928 -->
                            <!-- /react-text -->
                        </ul>
                    </span>
                    <span class="user-name">
                        <span>
                            <!-- react-text: 931 -->RePo 
                            <!-- /react-text -->
                            <span class="icon-balanceicon namepromotion" title="This user has activated the Name Promotion"></span>
                            <!-- react-text: 933 -->
                            <!-- /react-text -->
                        </span>
                        <!-- react-text: 934 -->: 
                        <!-- /react-text -->
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="msg-body">all of you</span>
            </li>
            <li class="msg-chat-message">
                <span class="user role-user">
                    <img class="user-logo" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1a/1a5e80deb58be484e49ea9a9434faa7a6528654b.jpg">
                        <div class="user-level-container">
                            <div class="user-level level-item level-50">50</div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="drop-down-container _3_options">
                            <ul class="user-dropdown-invisible">
                                <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Stats</li>
                                <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Tip</li>
                                <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Ignore</li>
                                <!-- react-text: 946 -->
                                <!-- /react-text -->
                            </ul>
                        </span>
                        <span class="user-name">
                            <span>
                                <!-- react-text: 949 -->Anonymous 
                                <!-- /react-text -->
                                <span class="icon-balanceicon namepromotion" title="This user has activated the Name Promotion"></span>
                                <!-- react-text: 951 --> 3
                                <!-- /react-text -->
                            </span>
                            <!-- react-text: 952 -->: 
                            <!-- /react-text -->
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="msg-body">kk</span>
                </li>
                <li class="msg-chat-message">
                    <span class="user role-user">
                        <img class="user-logo" src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/44/44c705474e17ebe8a2a9ef70467c20ee5add283e.jpg">
                            <div class="user-level-container">
                                <div class="user-level level-item level-50">52</div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="drop-down-container _3_options">
                                <ul class="user-dropdown-invisible">
                                    <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Stats</li>
                                    <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Tip</li>
                                    <li class="user-dropdown-entry">Ignore</li>
                                    <!-- react-text: 964 -->
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                </ul>
                            </span>
                            <span class="user-name">
                                <span>
                                    <!-- react-text: 967 -->Rrubinski. for  EM 
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                    <span class="icon-balanceicon namepromotion" title="This user has activated the Name Promotion"></span>
                                    <!-- react-text: 969 -->
                                    <!-- /react-text -->
                                </span>
                                <!-- react-text: 970 -->: 
                                <!-- /react-text -->
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="msg-body">which one u want?</span>
                    </li>
```

So far I created The list of elements, it's size is equal to 400 items (when chat is filled with messages); But still want to know if it is possible to track new elements instead of looping 400 times.

```
elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='msg-body']"));
            for (WebElement element: elementList) {
                if (element.getText().equals("nice")) {
                    System.out.println("Done");
                    System.out.println("List size: " + elementList.size());
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(200);
```

Comment: CAn you give us the HTML dom of the chat window?

Comment: @santhoshkumar yes, shure.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this let me know.

I assume that message will  be appended automatically in the dom with the same class similar as,

```
<span class="msg-body">which one u want?</span>
```

and the objective is to get the text of the last appended message. We can know the number of instances of the messages and get the text of the last one.

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='msg-body']")).size();
```

now get the text of the last message.

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='msg-body'][" + size + "]")).getText();
```

Later user Java API's or TestNG methods to do the validation of string message.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: `size` in your last code block is a string, not a variable.

Comment: Yes, we need to pass it as a variable

Comment: @santhoshkumar no, it gives me an exception:  Unable to locate element: //span[@class='msg-body'][104]

Comment: Are we having 104 messages flooded in the system? I will like to know the XPATH that we written is unique for messages alone?

Comment: @santhoshkumar, yes there are over 104 messages, when I load the page first time. The number grows up to 380-399.
The CSS Selector (From Firefox Inspector) is: li.msg-chat-message:nth-child(391) > span:nth-child(2)